# A result about infinite series: How to prove this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that, for some $N \geq 1$, some $s>1$, and some $M>0$, we have  $$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1 - \frac{A}{n} + \frac{f(n)}{n^s} $$ for all $n \geq N$, where $|f(n)| \leq M$ for all $n$. Then how to prove that the series $\sum a_n$ converges if $A > 1$ and diverges if $A \leq 1$?

I know that the following holds:

Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be two sequences of real numbers such that $a_n > 0$ and $b_n > 0$ for all $n \geq N$, for some fixed $N \geq 1$.

Then if there is a positive constant $r$ such that $$b_n - \frac{a_{n+1} \ b_{n+1}}{a_n} \geq r$$ for all $n \geq N$, then $\sum a_n$ converges.

If, on the other hand, 
$$b_n - \frac{a_{n+1} \ b_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq 0$$ for all $n \geq N$ and if $\sum 1/b_n$ diverges, then $\sum a_n$ diverges.

I wonder if there's a way of deducing the former result from the latter.

Comment: This is nothing but Gauss's test. [See this](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matngtb/Calculus/MA3110/Chapter%2013%20Special%20Test%20for%20Convergence.pdf).

Comment: Please do not modify entirely the purpose of the question after answers are posted. Asking to use Gauss test (one possible approach, perhaps not the most natural) changes the question.

Comment: Then do I pose a fresh question?

Answer (score 0):

The question when I posted this answer:

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that, for some $N \geq 1$, some $s>1$, and some $M>0$, we have  $$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1 - \frac{A}{n} + \frac{f(n)}{n^s} $$ for all $n \geq N$, where $|f(n)| \leq M$ for all $n$. Then how to prove that the series $\sum a_n$ converges if $A > 1$ and diverges if $A \leq 1$?

If $A\gt1$, choose $1\lt B\lt A$ and consider
$$
c_n=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^B\cdot\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}.
$$
Limited expansion of $c_n$ shows that
$$
c_n=1-\frac{A-B}n+o\left(\frac1n\right),
$$
hence $c_n\leqslant1$ for every $n$ large enough, that is, the sequence $(n^Ba_n)$ is ultimately decreasing, in particular, there exists $N'\geqslant N$ such that for every $n\geqslant N'$, one has $n^Ba_n\leqslant N^Ba_N$, that is,
$$
a_n\leqslant\frac{\alpha}{n^B},
$$
for some finite positive $\alpha$ hence the series $\sum\limits_na_n$ converges.

Likewise, if $A\leqslant1$, consider
$$
c_n=\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}.
$$
Can you carry on from here?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't make sense of the argument. Would you please take time reviewing my question?

Comment: `I'm sorry, but I couldn't make sense of` the problem you have with `the argument`. If you need explanations (about the answer), please explain (what your trouble with the answer is). // Regarding the revised version of your question, I already said what I thought of the fact that you completely modified the scope of the question AFTER some answers were posted: this is BAD. Hence, if your (unclear) comment asks that I address the revised version of your question, my answer is: No.

Answer (score 0):

One other way to do this is:

$ln( \frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n})= ln( 1 - \frac{A}{n} + O(\frac{1}{n^s}) )$

-->$ ln(A_{n+1}) -ln(A_n) = -\frac{A}{n} + O(\frac{1}{n^s}) $

You can say that partial sums are equal since both are divergent series:

--> $ln(A_{n+1}) -ln(A_o) = -A*H_n +O(G_n)$  where Hn is the partial harmonic sum and Gn the partial sum of $\frac{1}{n^s}$ . We have : $O(G_n) = o(A_n)$, and $H_n = ln(n) + y + o(1)$ so:

--> $ln(A_n) = ln(A_o) -A*y -A*ln(n) + o(1) $

--> $A_n$ ~ $K*n^{-A}  $

Conclusion:

If $A \leq 1$ , the series diverges
If $A > 1$, it converges